# MySQL UPDATE or INSERT depending on the existance of an ID

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I'm tracking visitor movements on a number of similar websites and have assigned goals to track with various values for each goal. As these goals are created dynamically I also need to update them dynamically. 
The relevant part of the mysql structure is as follows and it depicts the same 4 goals on 2 sites.
Note: The goals will always be the same for each site.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `goals` (
  `idsite` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idgoal` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `allow_multiple` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `revenue` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsite`,`idgoal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `goals` (`idsite`, `idgoal`, `name`, `allow_multiple`, `revenue`) VALUES
(10, 1, 'Product Benefits Video',   0,  2),
(10, 2, 'Agent Benefits Video',     0,  4),
(10, 3, 'Social Network Video',     0,  6),
(10, 4, 'MMP Overview Video',       1,  8),
(13, 1, 'Product Benefits Video',   0,  2),
(13, 2, 'Agent Benefits Video',     0,  4),
(13, 3, 'Social Network Video',     0,  6),
(13, 4, 'MMP Overview Video',       1,  8);
```

The above insert command is created from an array as folows along with the site_id.

```
$config['trackings'][1] = array('name'=>'Product Benefits Video',   'value'=>'2',   'multi'=>'0');
$config['trackings'][2] = array('name'=>'Agent Benefits Video', 'value'=>'3',   'multi'=>'0');
$config['trackings'][3] = array('name'=>'Social Network Video', 'value'=>'4',   'multi'=>'0');
$config['trackings'][4] = array('name'=>'MMP Overview Video',       'value'=>'5',   'multi'=>'1');
```

I will never need to delete a goal but I would like to know how to change the values and if the goal does not exist add it to all of the sites.

Example if I supply a new array as follows:

```
$config['trackings'][1] = array('name'=>'Product Benefits Video',   'value'=>'6',   'multi'=>'0');
$config['trackings'][2] = array('name'=>'Agent Benefits Video', 'value'=>'7',   'multi'=>'0');
$config['trackings'][3] = array('name'=>'Social Network Video', 'value'=>'8',   'multi'=>'1');
$config['trackings'][4] = array('name'=>'MMP Overview Video',       'value'=>'9',   'multi'=>'1');
$config['trackings'][5] = array('name'=>'MMP Details Video',        'value'=>'10',  'multi'=>'1');
```

I would like to add goal 5 and update the values and allow_multiple of the existing goals for each site.

I've thought about truncating the table and rewriting all the values from scratch but there are thousands of sites.
I've also played with replace, insert update and ended up pulling out my hair.

Is there an easier way to do this then emptying the lot?

Edit:
The End result would look like this

```
(10, 1, 'Product Benefits Video',   0,  6),
(10, 2, 'Agent Benefits Video',     0,  7),
(10, 3, 'Social Network Video',     1,  8),
(10, 4, 'MMP Overview Video',       1,  9),
(10, 5, 'MMP Details Video',        1,  10),
(13, 1, 'Product Benefits Video',   0,  6),
(13, 2, 'Agent Benefits Video',     0,  7),
(13, 3, 'Social Network Video',     1,  8),
(13, 4, 'MMP Overview Video',       1,  9);
(13, 5, 'MMP Details Video',        1,  10);
```

Edit: This will do all the updating quite easily

```
foreach($config['trackings'] as $id => $track)
{
    $s = "UPDATE `goals` SET `revenue` = ".$track['value'].", `allow_multiple` = ".$track['multi']." WHERE `idgoal` = '".$id."'";
}
```

But how to add the missing goal (5) at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a table of all sites?  If yes, you can use `REPLACE` like this:

```
REPLACE INTO goals (idsite, idgoal, name, allow_multiple, revenue)
SELECT idsite, 5, 'MMP Details Video', 1, 10 FROM sites;
```

Here `sites` is a table of all sites that have column `idsite` with the same meaning as column `idsite` in table `goals`.

This statement inserts new record into `goals` table for each site defined in `sites` table with values `idside, 5, 'MMP Details Video', 1, 10`, where `idsite` is a value taken from `idsite` column of `sites` table.  If record with the same `idsite` and `idgoal` already exists, it is replaced with new one.

Comment: Brilliant, tested and working like a charm! I never knew I could use strings as the selects like that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

use `INSERT IGNORE INTO table`

or `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Check out the mysql docs for more info on either command

Comment: Yes, I've been trying with that for some time, can you provide a simple example?

Comment: something like INSERT INTO goals (id, revenue, allow_multiple, ...) VALUES ($id,'blah', 'blah', ...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: `INSERT INTO goals (idsite, idgoal, revenue, allow_multiple) VALUES (10, 4, 44, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` = #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: Does it tell you where the error is? Whats the full error message?

Comment: It's OK it's solved now but the rest of the error said "near 1" which was must unhelpful.

Comment: yeah, computers can be quite cryptic at times

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured it out, I broke it into 2 parts.

```
$s = "SELECT MAX(`idgoal`) AS slice FROM goals";    //4
$slice = 4;
$track_update = array_slice($config['trackings'], 0, $slice, true);

foreach($track_update as $id => $track){ //4 queries
    $s = "UPDATE `goals` SET `revenue` = ".$track['value'].",
            `allow_multiple` = ".$track['multi']." WHERE `idgoal` = '".$id."'";
}

//now to add new values
$s = "SELECT DISTINCT(`idsite`) AS mid FROM goals";     //array(10,13)
$result = array(10,13);

$track_add = array_slice($config['trackings'], $slice, count($config['trackings']), true);

foreach($track_add as $id => $track){  //1 query for each site
    foreach($result as $idsite){
        $sx[] = "(
                        ".$idsite.", ".$id.",
                        '".$track['name']."',
                        ".$track['multi'].",
                        ".$track['value']."
                    )";
    }

    $s = "INSERT INTO `goals`
            (`idsite`, `idgoal`, `name`, `allow_multiple`, `revenue`) 
            VALUES ".implode(',',$sx);
}
```

5 Queries in total:

```
UPDATE `goals` SET `revenue` = 6, `allow_multiple` = 0 WHERE `idgoal` = '1'
UPDATE `goals` SET `revenue` = 7, `allow_multiple` = 0 WHERE `idgoal` = '2'
UPDATE `goals` SET `revenue` = 8, `allow_multiple` = 1 WHERE `idgoal` = '3'
UPDATE `goals` SET `revenue` = 9, `allow_multiple` = 1 WHERE `idgoal` = '4'
INSERT INTO `goals` (`idsite`, `idgoal`, `name`, `allow_multiple`, `revenue`) 
VALUES 
(10, 5, 'MMP Details Video', 1, 10),
(13, 5, 'MMP Details Video', 1, 10);
```